# Show that vectors of the form $(a,b,1)$ do not form a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that vectors of the form $(a,b,1)$ do not form a vector space

I tried using the vector space axioms to attack the problem but I am not going anywhere with this problem. I do not need a solution, I would prefer some suggestion or possible hints.

Comment: $(1,1,1) - (2,2,1)$???

Comment: Is the zero vector a member of this space? (That is, is there a vector in the space which when added to a vector $ \ \langle a,b,1 \rangle \ $ leaves it _unchanged_?)

Comment: To be honest...it fails quite a few axioms. Pick two random vectors, add them. Pick a random one, multiply by something other than one. Try and find a zero.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: Thank You. I realized my mistake

Comment: Good. Now you can write up what you have realized, and post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that vector space, V={v= (a,b,1)| a and b are real numbers}

1. Using the first axiom, i.e. closure under addition, we will show that this vector does not form a vector space: Let v1= (1,1,1) and v2= (1,2,1) be vectors of V, add them: v1+v2= (1,1,1)+ (1,2,1)= (2,3,2), and this vector is not part of our original vector space. Hence, the closure property fails under addition, therefore the vector does not form a vector space
2. More axioms can used to come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

They may or may not form a vector space; it depends on what operations are used.

For instance, suppose that addition is defined as $(a_1,b_1,1)+(a_2,b_2,1) := (a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,1)$, and that scalar multiplication is defined as $k\cdot(a,b,1) := (ka,kb,1)$. Then there should be no problem.

The moral is that a vector space is more than a set of vectors. It is a collection of vectors along with two operations, which the problem did not specify.

Comment: I appreciate the intent, but this answer is only going to confuse the OP even more.